# R Extract specific text from variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with this column:

```
VAR1
var_1.1
var_1.2
var_1.3
var_2.1
var_2.2
var_2.3
```

So what I would like is create a new column that keeps only

```
VAR1    VAR2
var_1.1  1
var_1.2  1
var_1.3  1
var_2.1  2
var_2.2  2
var_2.3  2
```

Basically retaining the text between "_" and "."

Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` to match one or more digits (`\\d+`) after the `_` followed by the `.`

```
df1 %>%
     mutate(VAR2 = str_extract(VAR1, "(?<=_)\\d+(?=\\.)"))
#     VAR1 VAR2
#1 var_1.1    1
#2 var_1.2    1
#3 var_1.3    1
#4 var_2.1    2
#5 var_2.2    2
#6 var_2.3    2
```

Or with `str_replace` to capture the digits as a group and in the replacement specify the backreference of the captured group

```
df1 %>% 
       mutate(VAR2 = str_replace(VAR1, ".*_(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1"))
```

---

Or with `sub` from `base R`

```
sub(".*_(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", df1$VAR1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(VAR1 = c("var_1.1", "var_1.2", "var_1.3", "var_2.1", 
"var_2.2", "var_2.3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use a non-regex approach if you have the same data as shown by using `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(df$VAR1)
#[1] 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 2.3
```

Now since you want the number before dot (`.`), we can `floor` the number we got from above.

```
df$Var2 <- floor(readr::parse_number(df$VAR1))
df

#     VAR1 Var2
#1 var_1.1    1
#2 var_1.2    1
#3 var_1.3    1
#4 var_2.1    2
#5 var_2.2    2
#6 var_2.3    2
```